# angularjs ns-show logic flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-show

I am a newbie in angularjs. I'm trying to show an html element depending on a property of the $scope object but without using any form element.

This is the snipped of code:

```
<div id="ListApp">
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        {{ myData.prova }}: {{ myData.logged }}
        <div id="secretContent" ng-show="myData.logged">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="elemento in lista">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="elemento.comprato" />
                <span ng-if="!elemento.comprato">{{ elemento.nome }}</span>
                <span ng-if="elemento.comprato" style="text-decoration:line-through;">{{ elemento.nome }}</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <input type='text' id='input_nome'/><button ng-click="aggiungi()">Aggiungi</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the controller part:

```
<script>
  var listaViaggio = angular.module('listApp', ['directive.g+signin']);
  listaViaggio.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope',function ListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lista = [];
    $scope.myData={};
    $scope.myData.prova="test";
    $scope.myData.logged=0;
    $scope.aggiungi = function(){
    $scope.lista.push({
      'nome':document.getElementById("input_nome").value,
      'comprato':false
    });
  };
    $scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-success', function (event, authResult) {$scope.myData.logged=1;console.log($scope.myData.logged);});
    $scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-failure', function (event, authResult) {$scope.myData.logged=0;console.log($scope.myData.logged);});
  }]);
</script>
```

As can be easily seen, I change the status of $scope.myData.logged on google+ sign in and I espect that the div with id secretContent will be shown or won't be shown depending on this property but I've seen that the truthfulness of the ng-show is evaluated only once and is not binded to the actual value of the property, so, when it changes, nothing happens.

What is wrong in my code? Which is the correct logic flow of the ng-show command and how to bind it to a $scope property?

Thanks in advance to everybody.

Comment: Need to use `$scope.$apply()` in the `$on` callbacks.

Comment: Great, it works! Thank you very much. Just a question: why bidirectional data binding doesn't work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Use $scope.$apply() whenever the values get changed.

$scope.$apply() will update the page content.

Comment: Hi astro, what do you exactly mean? which is the best way for you? I am a newbie and each contribution is highly appreciated. Thank you.